# Is there a way to chunk 2 or more repititions of a tag in a tagged sentence using nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, chunking

I'm trying to use the nltk module in python to chunk together any instances where two to five nouns occur in sequence.

This is the code I am using:

```
parse_pattern  = "Keyword: {< N>{2,5}}"
keyword_parser = nltk.RegexpParser(parse_pattern)
result = keyword_parser.parse(sentence)
```

I makes sense that this bit should do the trick: `Keyword: {< N>{2,5}}`

I even found an example in the book Natural Language Processing with Python that uses the above bit completely analogously: `NOUNS: {< N.*>{4,}}` where the authors explain that that bit of code should chunk 4 or more nouns.

However, I get an error when I run the above code:

```
ValueError: Illegal chunk pattern: {< N>{2,5}}
```

Note: I also tried the above using `{< N.*>{2,5}}` (with the dot star solely because the author of the aforementioned book did) with no luck.

Any help in how to chunk two or more repetitions of a tag would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The ValueError is probably triggered by the space between the opening angle bracket and the N.

`parse_pattern = "Keyword: {<N>{2,5}}"` rather than
`parse_pattern = "Keyword: {< N>{2,5}}"`

Also, don't worry about using the syntax with the extra dot star, as this is only necessary if you are trying to match all tags that *start* with, here, N.

If all fails, you may try the alternative expression which doesn't require the {min, max} syntax for the occurrences range.
`parse_pattern = "Keyword: {<N><N><N>?<N>?<N>?}"`

And if that even fails, maybe try just `parse_pattern = "Keyword: {<N>}"`, this hopefully would get *something* to work or otherwise maybe help pinpoint what else may be wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

nltk tags nouns with the following tags:

- `<NN>` for a singular noun
- `<NNP>` for a singular proper noun
- `<NNS>` for a plural noun
- `<NNPS>` for a plural proper noun

Thus if you want to catch any of these between two and five times, you'll want the regex:

```
<NN.*>{2,5}
```

With your example, that would be:

```
parse_pattern  = "Keyword: {<NN.*>{2,5}}"
keyword_parser = nltk.RegexpParser(parse_pattern)
result         = keyword_parser.parse(sentence)
```

Note that `sentence` must be tagged, e.g.

```
sentence = [("dog", "NN"), ("David", "NNP"), ("cats", "NNS")]
```

Answer (score 0):

look for the code of regex.py package, that the method of tag_pattern2re_pattern(), which functionality convert tag_pattern to correct regular expression. Whereas the constant parameter CHUNK_TAG_PATTERN that is immutable, which starts with some special character and ends with special character, such like '('、' '、'<'、')'、'>'、'>'. So the tag pattern `CHUNK:{<V.*><TO><V.*>}` is correct, but the tag pattern `CHUNK:{<V>.*<TO><V.*>{1,}}` is incorrect